# How do I test a single function on the Solana VM?

Tags: rust, testing, sealevel

Say I have a test function like this:

```
#[test]
fn my_test() {
    assert_eq!(2 + 2, 4)
}
```

I could test this with regular `cargo test` but that will run the function on my OS, not as it would run in a Solana transaction.

I could also use `solana-program-test` but then I need to do a bunch of setup and send transactions when all I want is to see if a single function does what I expect.

How do I do `cargo test` but make the code run in Sealevel?

Comment: The `solana-program-test` model is going to be the best bet at the moment unfortunately. If you want some code to mimic the runtime, you need to compile it to bpf and then run it through the rbpf vm. There are some neat tests in rbpf doing that https://github.com/solana-labs/rbpf/blob/main/tests/execution.rs -- so once you can compile your code into BPF instructions, you could just run a test like these!